# retrieve data from gridview in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've been looking for this a while but I still don't know how I can get data from the selected rouw out of a Gridview in Asp.net vb.

I tried this but then i get this: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Dim email As String
email = Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call DataBind before:

```
Gridview1.DataBind();
Dim email As String
email = Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
email = GridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Currentrow is not a member of Gridview it says

Comment: write this under grid's click or double click event

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it may work

```
Dim email As String
email = Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Value is not a member of tablecell it says

Comment: Try email = Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells("columnName").Value.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Accessing BoundField Column
    string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

    //Accessing TemplateField Column controls
    string country = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;

    lblValues.Text = "<b>Name:</b> " + name + " <b>Country:</b> " + country;
}
```

Refer the below link.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx